# Problemas al recuperrar array con info de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer el login con Clases y Objetos.

La cosa a sido que al usar Clases y Objetos la variable registro que guarda un array asociativo es inaccesible ahora y me da un error,

```
require_once('conf_db.php');

class BaseDatos{

    protected $con;
    protected $db;
    protected $registro;

    public function conectar() {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
        if ($this->con == '0') DIE("Lo sentimos, no se ha podido conectar con MySQL: ".mysqli_error());
        //$this->db = mysqli_select_db(DBNAME, $this->con);
        if (DBNAME == '0') DIE("Lo sentimos, no se ha podido conectar con la base datos: ".DBNAME);
        return true;
    }
    public function desconectar() {
        if ($this->conectar->con) {
            mysqli_close($this->$con);
        }
    }

    public function consulta(){
        $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sentencia);

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $registro[] = $fila;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ahora el archivo seguridad que hará la comprobación de la contraseña y creara la sesión.

```
<?php 

    include('../include/conexion.php');
    $db = new BaseDatos();
    $db->conectar();
    $db->consulta();

    if($db->conectar()){
        //Datos recogidos de login.php
        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
        $pass = $_POST['contrasena'];
        //Para una mayor seguridad pasamos la contraseña a un hash
        $hash = password_hash($_POST["contrasena"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        foreach ($registro as $registros) {
            $pass_bd = $registros['contrasena'];
            $user_bd = $registros['usuario'];
            if (($user_bd = $user) AND (password_verify($pass_bd,$hash))) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['logueado']=TRUE;
                header('Location: control.php');
            }
            else{
                header('Location: login.php');
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

no estas retornando la data de la consulta fuera de tu funcion:

prueba así:

```
public function consulta(){
    $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sentencia);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $fila;

}
```

y en la funcion de la consulta, es un unico registro que sacas de la base de datos, prueba así la validacion:

```
$datos = $db->consulta();
$pass_bd = $datos['contrasena'];
$user_bd = $datos['usuario'];
if (($user_bd = $user) AND (password_verify($pass_bd,$hash))) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logueado']=TRUE;
    header('Location: control.php');
}
else{
    header('Location: login.php');
    echo "Error";
}
```

**porque no es requerible un foreach para lo que intentas hacer. Por cierto, filtra la data que busca de usuarios para la auitenticacion, algo asi:**

```
public function consulta($X){
    $sentencia = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = $X';
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sentencia);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $fila;

}
```

y la consultas de esta manera:

```
$datos = $db->consulta($_POST['usuario']);
```

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar, ahora entiendo mejor el concepto y en lo q fallaba gracias.

Comment: ok marca como respuesta. saludos

Comment: Me genera otro error... Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MC/APP/login 2/seguridad.php on line 14

Comment: como te comente en los ejemplo, no requieres de un foreach para validar la informacion de un solo registro extraido de la base de datos, pues al validar un usuario enel login, debes filtrar la informacion que rescatas de tu base

Answer (score 0):

El fallo es que no estas retornando los datos desde tu sentencia como ya te han mencionado, aun así, te he modificado un poco la función de tu consulta para que sea más útil, así podrás trabajar con diferentes sentencias y no una única.

Por otro lado tu [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) no te va funcionar, le estas pasando los dos parámetros haseada y el primero no debe estar haseado.

*Tu código:*

```
password_verify($pass_bd,$hash)
```

Recuerda, `$pass_bd` debe estar haseado en tu *Base de datos* por seguridad y para verificarlo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Contraseña usuario.
$pass = $_POST['contrasena'];
//Verificamos contraseña.
password_verify($pass,$pass_bd)
```

### Posible ejemplo:

**BaseDatos**

```
require_once('conf_db.php');

class BaseDatos{

    protected $con;
    protected $db;
    protected $registro;

    public function conectar() {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);
        if ($this->con == '0') DIE("Lo sentimos, no se ha podido conectar con MySQL: ".mysqli_error());
        //$this->db = mysqli_select_db(DBNAME, $this->con);
        if (DBNAME == '0') DIE("Lo sentimos, no se ha podido conectar con la base datos: ".DBNAME);
        return true;
    }

    public function desconectar() {
        if ($this->conectar->con) {
            mysqli_close($this->$con);
        }
    }

    //Pasamos nuestra consulta directamente.
    public function consultaRetorno($sql){            
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);    
        return $result;                
    }
}
```

*Comprobamos al usuario*

```
<?php 

    include('../include/conexion.php');
    $db = new BaseDatos();
    $db->conectar();        

    if($db->conectar()){
        //Datos recogidos de login.php
        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
        $pass = $_POST['contrasena'];
        //Para una mayor seguridad pasamos la contraseña a un hash
        $hash = password_hash($_POST["contrasena"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //Creamos sentencia
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user'";
        //Pasamos sentencia a nuestra función.
        $result = $db->consultaRetorno($sql);
        //Retornamos datos
        $registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($registro['usuario'] == $user) {

            if (password_verify($pass,$registro['contrasena'])) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['logueado']=TRUE;
                header('Location: control.php');
            } else {
                echo "Error contraseña";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Error usuario";
        }            
    }
?>
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)